# Thread-safe API request duration calculation on iOS

Tags: swift, multithreading, thread-safety, urlsession, urlrequest

I would need to calculate the duration of each API request after we receive the response. It would be easy to do:

```
func performRequest(request: URLRequest) {
    let startDate = Date()
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        let duration = Date().timeIntervalSince(date: startDate)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when we do multiple requests at the same time - we might end up in a situation when the first request is calculating the `duration` while the next request already entered the `performRequest` method and changed the `startDate`. This will lead in incorrect `duration` calculation.

I am curious to know how can we make sure that all the requests and duration calculations are concurrent and thread-safe? And that the duration is calculated properly for each of the simultaneous requests without ending up in weird states.

Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't cause issue there, as `startDate` is a local instance, you should always have the correct date. But you might also be interested into `URLSessionTaskMetrics`

Comment: Multiple requests = multiple call stacks. Each call stack gets its own local variables. Your described "situation" will not occur with your current code. It would occur, if you used shared variables, e.g. class members or static variables.

Comment: absolutely, you are 100% right, thank you so much for replies everyone! i think i did too much overthinking here :)